# Copying first few characters to a new string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

If I have a `string courseID` with a string that has the general form of `"MATH202"`. The first few letters represent the subject of the class. If i want to extract those first 4 characters and set a new `string subject` to those 4 characters how would I do so?

Could I loop through the first string 4 times and set that letter to the second string with that letter?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: `courseID.substr(0, 4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
string subject = courseID.substr(0, 4);
```

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly. Thanks for the help. Will accept the answer once I'm able too.